# Recreation of Fragments Using Navigation Component

Tags: android, android-livedata, android-jetpack, android-architecture-navigation

In my `onViewCreated()` of my fragment which contains a list, I observe for my live data like below:

```
     searchViewModel.allVideos.observe(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
        searchAdapter.updateList(it)
    })
```

whenever one of the list's item is clicked, it will go to the details page using the navigation component.

```
      ...
       val bundle = bundleOf("postId" to post!!.id)
        v?.findNavController()?.navigate(R.id.action_to_detailsFragment, bundle, null, extras)
```

but when user returns to list, he/she sees duplicate items in the list. The `onViewCreated` is called again and new items are added to the list. Navigation component replaces fragments :(((

Can anybody help me?

Comment: remove the observer after you update the list

Comment: @coroutineDispatcher I removed it but the problem is still exists

Comment: Are you accumulating the video list in the `searchAdapter`?

Comment: @SanlokLee Yes, I do.

Comment: @SalmanSeifian, a better design is to make `allVideos` to have the full list of videos instead of having them piece by piece and accumulate in the adapter.

Comment: maybe you can clear the list first ?

Answer (score 0):

Please refer [EventObserver](https://gist.github.com/JoseAlcerreca/e0bba240d9b3cffa258777f12e5c0ae9) by @JoseAlcerreca, This allow you to observe event only once. Reference article [LiveData By JoseAlcerreca](https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/livedata-with-snackbar-navigation-and-other-events-the-singleliveevent-case-ac2622673150)

or

Instead of updating your list on observer callback, you should replace entire list of the adapter.